# Payment gateway performance comparison - is there any site which provides this data?

Tags: payment-gateway

This is a question specifically addressed towards site owners who use payment gateway solutions for India. Is there a site which provides regular updates on the performance of payment gateways?

I know about the [Indian Railways performance reports](https://www.irctc.co.in/betaDoc/Bank_Reports_July.xls). Is there any other site which covers payment gateways like EBS, CCAvenue and the other payment gateways?

Answer (score 2):

[This is a good article](http://www.freshbooks.com/blog/2010/09/29/online-payments-gateway-performance/) going over payment gateway performance